# How to make a confirm for onclick event in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, onclick

I have this button in my view:

```
  <input type="image" name="Command" onclick="CallBtn('SConform')" value="SConform" src='../Images/conform.png' style="float: left;"/>
```

which calls an action on the controller but i need to add a js confirm window and make it either go ahead with the call if true, or do nothing if false. Does anybody know how could I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `confirm`, it's not pretty though:

```
function CallBtn(id) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure?") return;
    ... rest of existing code...
```

if you're using jquery or bootstrap then there's nicer options.

Comment: It's working on the true way, but when i press cancel my application crashes.. Any thoughts on how to solve that? +1 anyways because it's a start.

Comment: Ended up using another solution sending a different action if the confirm() was denied but it was based on your answer so I'll accept it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try inline confirm dialog like following :

```
<input type="image" name="Command" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure ?')) { CallBtn('SConform') }">
```

**[Example HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/988n5dhu/)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's working on the true way, but when i press cancel my application crashes.. Any thoughts on how to solve that? +1 anyways because it's a start.

Comment: Does it give an error when crashing? The code above works by itself, so it must be something else going on in your code. Step thru the debugger.